# oracle error, column not allowed here

Tags: oracle, ora-00984

I haven't used Oracle for a while so I'm a bit rusty.

This is my table:

```
create table calendar(
username VARCHAR2(12),
content VARCHAR2(100),
dateContent DATE,
type CHAR(3) CHECK (type IN ('PUB', 'PRV')));
```

But when I try to insert a value like this:

```
insert into calendar
(username, content, dateContent, type) 
values
(chris, assignment due, to_date('01-OCT-2010 13:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'), PUB)
/
```

I am getting:

```
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

pointing to the type column at the end. I have a feeling I'm not getting something right with the DATE field as I've never really used it.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to put quotes round the varchar2 values

Something like

```
insert into calendar(username, 
                     content, 
                     dateContent, 
                     type) 
  values('chris', 
         'assignment due', 
         to_date('01-OCT-2010 13:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI'), 
         'PUB');
```

Comment: It is a misleading error message and the sort of thing which catches us all out, rusty or not.

Comment: Note, that you have to use single quotes - using double quotes resolves into just the same error. Probably because the double quotes are reserved for the table names, column names etc., which explains the error message.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Could it be because `type` is a [Oracle reserved word](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) ?</s>

Looks like this is not an issue. Read the comment by APC.

I'm not deleting this answer because I find the comment useful.

Comment: TYPE is a reserved but not the sort of reserved word which can't be used.  This is because TYPE only became a reserved word in Oracle8 (the so-called ORDBMS release).  By then there was a huge codebase in existence which had legitimately used TYPE as a column name.  For instance the data dictionary's USER_SOURCE view.  So banning the use of TYPE as a column name would break a lot of applications.